# FMINSEARCH only accepts inputs of data type double (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Define the poles of the lucid factors as independent variables (starting
solution for the optimization routine)

```
x0 = {[-0.4 -0.4 -0.4 -0.4]};
```

Evaluation of the objective function

```
filename = 'getrcsu';
```

Declare the function to be minimized

```
x = fminsearch(@(m,n,w1,w2,h,G,hd,mpoles,dpoles) filename,x0);
```

When I try the run the coding above. Matlab displays the error message:

```
FMINSEARCH only accepts inputs of data type double.
```

I dont understand what is the problem. Please help me on this. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by your use of the curly braces around x0.  You are defining it to be a cell array, instead of a matrix.

```
x0 = [-0.4 -0.4 -0.4 -0.4];
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply prototoast.I still have a few questions here.

1)If mpoles and dpoles are expressed in the starting solution,should I insert them in the bracket after @ in the coding above??? 2)I encountered another form of error which is "Conversion to double from tf is not possible".